# Facebook iOS read only?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, stream

I've used the iOS Facebook SDK before to post to one's timeline or share through an app. However, now I want to just read a public stream, a politician's Facebook stream. This is easy with Twitter. How do I do it with Facebook. I don't want to log in or any app id's. I just want to read the public stream of a particular user, that's all.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't anymore. Even though the information is "public" the graph API was changed last summer to require an access token even to do that.

> Graph API PROFILE_ID/feed and PROFILE_ID/posts now requires
>   access_token
>
> As stated last week, the Graph API PROFILE_ID/feed/ for a Page,
>   Application, User or Group and PROFILE_ID/posts for a Page or User now
>   requires a valid access_token to access the wall or posts of the
>   corresponding object (where previously no access_token was required).

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

<strike>Basically you now are required to create a facebook app and get an AppId. You don't actually have to "log in"; since you just want public data you only need to request a valid access token with your AppId.</strike>

See this example/blog (It's PHP but the important bit is the last example showing that you only need to do a simple HTTP request to get the token):
 http://illuminatikarate.com/blog/facebook-graph-api-requires-access-token-for-feed-access/ .

It would appear the moving target that is the Facebook API ... has moved again. You can no longer just do that. You actually have to request the `read_stream` permission even to read public data.

Comment: Thanks. I had to create a dummy application on my Facebook page to allow users to let the app sign them in. Then I accessed the public data of a specific user. Twitter is far easier for this and less intrusive to the user just looking to "read"

Answer (score 0):

You need an access token to get a Facebook user feed, even if the feed is public.

For instance, lets take Mark Zuckerberg public feed: http://www.facebook.com/zuck

Now if we try to query it using graph api explorer:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=4%2Ffeed

or directly via facebook graph:
https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/feed

We'll get: "An access token is required to request this resource."

So you need the read_stream permission for that in your access token.